# How can I do form valitation feedback in web.py

Tags: python, forms, web.py

I want write form in html, like

```
form    
    input type.....   
    input type.....
```

then write this in py:

```
f = forms.register_form()
if not f.validates():
    return render.register(f)
```

the question is, if the form is not pass validation, how could I feedback the information to user.
is there anything like #springbind in velocity?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Do not use HTML for it but rather mark the code as code by indenting it with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer with a snippet from a web.py project of mine:

```
bookeditform = form.Form(
    form.Textbox('title', form.notnull),
    form.Textbox('author', form.notnull),
    form.Textbox('year', 
        form.Validator('Must be a number', lambda x: not x or int(x) > 0)),
)

# ...

class NewBookHandler:
    def GET(self):
        f = bookeditform()
        return render.bookedit(f, "New book")

    def POST(self):
        f = bookeditform()
        if f.validates():
            newid = db.insert('book', title=f.d.title, 
                              author=f.d.author, year=f.d.year)
            raise web.seeother('/book/%s' % newid)
        else:
            return render.bookedit(f, "New book")
```

A recap:

- In the handler, on `GET`, simply render the empty form.
- On `POST`, load the form, and check if its validates.

  - If it does, do the required action, and **redirect the user to a success page**. Never render anything on `POST`, because the user can refresh the page, re-doing the same action.
  - If it doesn't, re-render the form (it'll contain the entered data, and error messages will be displayed).

Comment: It doesn't show any error messages to me. What to do ? pls help

Comment: @krishna222, I have `form.notnull` as a validator for some of the form fields, and `$:form.render()` actually shows "Required" on fields marked with `notnull`.